# New poly-word closure reasons need punctuation

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions

I applaud the new reasons for closing a question. 
But recently I voted to close [this question (Reason for Unexpected Shutdown …)](https://superuser.com/questions/612281/reason-for-unexpected-shutdown-with-unexpected-symbols), and then I went to look at it, and it looked something like this:

> ### put on hold as unclear what you're asking by [ultrasawblade](https://superuser.com/users/51705/ultrasawblade), [Breakthrough](https://superuser.com/users/6887/breakthrough), [Nifle](https://superuser.com/users/2013/nifle), [AthomSfere](https://superuser.com/users/208421/athomsfere), [Scott](https://superuser.com/users/150988/scott) 17 secs ago
>
> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.  As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Actual image: [image]

This strikes me as hard to read. 
I suggest that the words “unclear what you're asking” be put into quotes,
or set off with some other form of punctuation, or perhaps a different font.

Also, in the phrase

> ## As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly ...

there’s one of each kind of apostrophe (the first one is straight/vertical, the second is slanted/curved).